# changing a `li` to input when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

I am wanting to change an `<li>` to a text input with the value of the `<li>` when an edit button is pressed

My solution for this is

```js
let taskList = document.querySelector("#taskList");
const addTaskInput = document.querySelector("#addTaskInput");
const addTaskButton = document.querySelector("#addTaskButton");

const addTask = () => {
    if (addTaskInput.value != " ") {
        let taskItem = document.createElement("li");
        taskItem.textContent = addTaskInput.value;
        let checkBox = document.createElement("input");
        checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkBox");
        let removeItem = document.createElement("button");
        removeItem.setAttribute("class", "remove");
        removeItem.textContent = "Delete";
        let editItem = document.createElement("button");
        editItem.textContent = "Edit"
        editItem.setAttribute("class", "edit");
        taskList.appendChild(taskItem);
        taskItem.appendChild(checkBox);
        taskItem.appendChild(removeItem);
        taskItem.appendChild(editItem);
        addTaskInput.value = " ";
    };
}
addTaskButton.addEventListener("click", addTask);

// const checkbox = document.querySelector("input").addEventListener('change', () => {
// if (checkbox.checked == true) {
// console.log("check test");
// } else {
// console.log("not working");
// }
// });


addTaskInput.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        addTask();
    }
});    
                                                 
taskList.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if(event.target.tagName == "BUTTON") {
        if (event.target.className == "remove") {
            let taskItem = event.target.parentNode;
            taskList = taskItem.parentNode;
            taskList.removeChild(taskItem);
        } else if (event.target.className == "edit") {
            event.target.setAttribute("class", "done");
            let taskItem = event.target.parentNode;
            taskList = taskItem.parentNode;
            let editMode = document.createElement("input");
            editMode.setAttribute("type", "text");
            editMode.setAttribute("value", taskItem.textContent);
            taskList.replaceChild(taskItem, editMode);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
ul li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem .25rem;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
ul li button {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  border: none;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  background: none;
  font-size: .75rem;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
  color: #000;
}
ul li button:hover {
  color: #777;
}
ul li input {
  float: right;
}

#addTaskButton {
  background: #fff;
  border: .5px solid black;
  margin: 1rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: none;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#addTaskButton:hover {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul id="taskList">
        </ul>
        <div id="add-task-area">
             <input type="text" id="addTaskInput" value="">
             <button id="addTaskButton">Add Task</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Essentially rebuilding the element and using the textContent as the value
(will add the changes to the `<li>` after solving this problem.
This solution doesn't work. Is this not how replaceChild works? Also there must be a less verbose way of implementing this? 
JavaScript only please, also can you please explain any answers or feedback

https://codepen.io/hellojessicagraham/pen/Yxojqe

Comment: Please create a complete working example - a snippet/jsfiddle/codepen.

Comment: @Dekel Please don't ask people to post their code on 3rd party sites. Those links can become dead over time and then the question here will make no sense. Stack Overflow has a "Code Snippet" option that you can insert right into your question, right here to create working versions of code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus some of the external libraries will not work inside SO snippets due to CORS, so sometimes you must use jsfiddle/codepen :)

Comment: @Dekel But, those scenarios are not the norm as most libraries have public CDNs that are not blocked by CORS. As such, SO is always preferred.

Comment: I agree that so is prefered

Answer (score 1):

Reverse arguments of replaceChild. First argument is new node and second argument is old node which needs to be replaced.

```
taskList.replaceChild(editMode,taskItem)
```